# Are algebraic predicates supported in Mercury?

Tags: mercury

I'm very new to Mercury and logic programming in general.  I haven't found a numeric example like this in the docs or samples...

Take the example predicate:

```
:- pred diffThirtyFour(float, float).
:- mode diffThirtyFour(in, out) is det.

diffThirtyFour(A,B) :-
    ( B = A + 34.0 ).
```

With this, A must be ground, and B is free.  What if I want A to be free and B to be ground (eg, adding `mode diffThirtyFour(out,in) is det.`).  Can this sort of algebra be performed at compile time?  I could easily define another predicate, but that doesn't seem very logical...

**Update**

So, something like this kind of works:

```
:- pred diffThirtyFour(float, float).
:- mode diffThirtyFour(in, out) is semidet.
:- mode diffThirtyFour(out, in) is semidet.

diffThirtyFour(A,B) :-
    ( B = A + 34.0, A = B - 34.0 ).
```

A little wary of the `semidet`, and the redundancy of the second goal.  Is this the only way of doing it?

**Update 2**

This might be the answer...it issues a warning at compile time about the disjunct never having any solutions.  A correct warning, but perhaps unnecessary code-smell?  This does what I need, but if there are better solutions out there, feel free to post them...

```
:- pred diffThirtyFour(float, float).
:- mode diffThirtyFour(in, out) is det.
:- mode diffThirtyFour(out, in) is det.



diffThirtyFour(A,B) :-
    ( A = B - 34.0, 
      B = A + 34.0 
    ; 
     error("The impossible happened...")
    ).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just discovered the ability to enter [different clauses for different modes](https://www.mercurylang.org/information/doc-release/mercury_ref/Different-clauses-for-different-modes.html#Different-clauses-for-different-modes).  This isn't quite an algebraic solver (which I wouldn't have expected anyway), but offers the precise organizational structure I was looking for:

```
:- pred diffThirtyFour(float, float).
:- mode diffThirtyFour(in, out) is det.
:- mode diffThirtyFour(out, in) is det.
:- pragma promise_pure(diffThirtyFour/2).

diffThirtyFour(A::out,B::in)  :- A = B - 34.0.
diffThirtyFour(A::in, B::out) :- B = A + 34.0.
```

As described in the link, the `promise_pure` pragma is required because this feature can be used to break semantic consistency.  It would also suffice to use the `promise_equivalent_clauses` pragma, which promises logical consistency without purity.  It is still possible to declare clauses with inconsistent semantics with the `impure` keyword in the pred declaration.

Interestingly, addition and subtraction in the standard `int` module *are* inversible, but not in the `float` module.  Perhaps the choice was made because of possible errors in floating point arithmetic....